# How can I separate expressions in Module without suppressing output?

Tags: plotting, programming, dynamic, column

I want to show a progress indicator while statements in a Module are processed.

Outside a Module this ca be done like this:

```
messages = {};    
Column[{ Dynamic[zeilenZ]
,  Pane[            
     ProgressIndicator[               
      Dynamic[zeilenZ] 
     , {0, Dynamic[length]}
    ]
   ]   (* Pane *)
  , Dynamic[TextGrid[messages]]
  }
]                 (* a semicolon after the bracket would suppress the ProgressIndicator! *) 
zeilenZ = 0;      (* many computations following *)
```

However, if I put this sequence of statements into a Module expression, I get an error message `Set::write: Tag Times in Null ... is Protected.`. If I put a semicolon after the closing bracket of `Column`, the next line would no longer be understood as a multiplication of `Column[....]` and what follows it, in my case `zeilenZ`. But the ProgressIndicator would be suppressed too!

The same would happen, if I would plot something instead of `Column`.

Of course, I could assign the whole Column statement (or Plot statement) to a variable, **but how could I show it on the screen?**

The only way out I have conceived so far is to assign the result of the `Column` statement to a variable `col` (which initially is assigned the empty list `{}`) and display that with `Dynamic[col]` before using the module. It looks like `col` having to be a global variable for that purpose and my ProgressIndiator appears where the `Dynamic[col]` is output.

**Are there better ways to achieve my objective?**

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Monitor[Module[{s}, 
  s = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t] Cos[t + y[t]], y[0] == 1}, 
    y, {t, 0, 100000}, StepMonitor :> (time = t)]], 
 ProgressIndicator[time/100000]]
```

[image]

or this:

```
tEnd = 100000;
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[currentTime], {0, tEnd}]

currentTime = 0;
Module[{s}, 
 s = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t] Cos[t + y[t]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {t, 0, tEnd}, EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = t;)]]
```

Have fun!